# How does different components communicate in MVVM in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, mvvm, communication

knowing that in typical MVC implemented iOS projects the Model, view, Controller will communicate in the below patterns.

View to Controller using IBActions, Delegation

Controller to Model using direct method invocations or call backs using blocks

Model to Controller using Delegation or KVO

Controller to View using IBOutlets

correct me if i was wrong anyplace.

My question is how this would happen in a typical MVVM implemented Projects.I want the best communication approaches between components & please justify also how a particular one is better than others if anything has more than one way of communication availability.for example (Delegation & callBacks) mostly its preferable going with Call backs for more precise & readable code.

I will also up vote those who gives me the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Data Flow describe the communication of elements in MVVM:

```
Data Flow
1. UI calls method from ViewModel (Presenter).
2. ViewModel executes Use Case.
3. Use Case combines data from User and Repositories.
4. Each Repository returns data from a Remote Data (Network), Persistent DB Storage Source or In-memory Data (Remote or Cached).
5. Information flows back to the UI where we display the list of items.
```

In this article, there is a more detailed description of MVVM
https://tech.olx.com/clean-architecture-and-mvvm-on-ios-c9d167d9f5b3

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I agree with you about what you pointed out about MVC. I just want to make a discussion about MVC and MVVM from my point of views

- From the architecture point of view, in the typical MVC setup, Models represent data, Views represent user interfaces, and View Controllers mediate the interactions between the V and M. The relationships between VC and V, VC and M are tight coupling. Moreover, from that setup, VC will handle a lot of logics and become massive due to over responsibilities.

  In MVVM, VC and V are be treated as a component, M still works as it is in MVC. The new component VM, which encapsulates data/logics that the **V** can bind to and any logics and action can be performed. The connection between V and VM is loose coupling. Why? because the V keeps referent of VM, however, the VM doesn't know the V and it just can be communication with the V via binding system.
- From the advantages of MVVM in application development point of view, in which it comes with several benefits. We can easy to write Unit Test to test the logic of VM. We can easy to modify the V (UI) due to now it is just binding to VM.

Comment: Its good to know all these things but i know these as well and its well.But i am asking specially how theses components interact each other in iOS app development is considered.you could please tell the design patterns for better communication between different components.Thanks for your reply.got some insights that i do not know earlier.

Comment: You can't really do MVVM in iOS without some other framework such as React because iOS doesn't have a native data binding framework

Comment: i pretty sure that to implement MVVM in ios we really no need to have obviously a binding mechanism unlike other technologies like C#.More over in iOS we are having KVO for observing and notifying.But i agree in iOS there is no such powerful binding mechanism like Mac OSX.Thanks for this.

Comment: I am really expecting what are all different communication patterns between components in MVVM.that others are doing in MVVM iOS projects with out ReactCocoa, KVOController and other third party support.

Comment: if you don't intend to adopt the binding system, a suggestion is that using delegate instead.